# Current web based ePub reader

Tags: javascript, epub

I'm trying to find a web based ePub reader (in Javascript probably) that is currently being developed and is well documented. All of the things that Google turns up have either not been touched in months/years or are rather poorly documented.

Comment: Why not write one yourself? Think about it: an ePub is just a zip (there are plenty of JS zip APIs) containing some XHTML (which the browser can display natively).

Comment: That seems to have been sort of what everybody has done (and then lost interest).

Comment: What purpose do you want an epub reader for?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496712/web-based-epub-reader-using-javascript-and-html/14514064?

Comment: Have you looked at Readium??

Answer (score 1):

I've tried most everything out there and given the answers suggested here and in other threads:

epub.js is easy to get to work but sparsely documented and does not really look to be under serious development. I couldn't customize it to my needs.

Readium is fairly hard to get to work. I got it to build just now and I'm trying to hook it into my epub system which is probably going to work but is more work than expected.

**Update:** I've now spent hours to try to get Readium to work and the project is too complex and the documentation too lacking to get anywhere.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do?  It sounds like you have a collection of EPUBs you want to make web-accessible.  Is that right?  ReadiumJS is being actively developed and is probably a safe bet on that front.  I have used epub.js a bit and found it very easy to get working, although (like you) I found it difficult to customize.  Anyway, I'm interested to know if you find a better solution than Readium.

Comment: I'm still trying to get Readium working but it is slow going and the priorities of the project do not seem to fit with what I'm aiming for. One show stopper is that it doesn't load my epub files and it's unclear why. I'm thinking of reviving epub.js because that's simple enough to be able to develop out.